# Which letter completes this puzzle?

Tags: no-computers

As shown in picture below, which letter completes the puzzle ? 
It bogging me for few days already ...

[image: Puzzles with decagon shapes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This image represents an:

> [Atbash cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash)
>
>  (each letter is encrypted with the letter above or below it)
>
> ```
> ABCDEFGHIJKLM
> ZYXWVUTSRQPON
> ```

So the answer is:

> O

Comment: :P Your answer looks nicer I'll delete mine

Comment: @as4s4hetic really, you should get the credit, you ninja'd me

Comment: Yes but I also wrote that O's the 11th letter from the end when it's actually the 12th and I just can't count